# Set author's last name in small caps but avoid them for editors, translators, etc using biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm using biblatex and I need author's last name in small caps, so I do this:

```
\renewcommand\mkbibnamelast[1]{\textsc{#1}}
```

So I get "SMITH, John" and that's what I needed. But I also get for example:

> ALCINOOS (1990). Enseignement des doctrines de Platon. Ed. por J.
>   WHITTAKER y P. LOUIS. Paris: Belles Lettres.

And the problem is I don't want that editors, translators, etc in small caps, because in spanish is not correct.

Edit: As of March 2016 (biblatex 3.3), you need `\mkbibnamefamily`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Small capitals can be applied selectively using `\ifcurrentname`. The example below applies `\textsc` only to the last names of the fields `labelname`, `author` (or `editor`, in the absence of `author`). The results are demonstrated with `verbose-trad1`, but the solution should work for most styles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-trad1]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifmknamesc{\textsc{#1}}{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifmknamesc} and test {\ifuseprefix} }
    {\textsc{#1}}
    {#1}}

\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
               or test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
               or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}} and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) }}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent
\citeauthor{aristotle:poetics,gaonkar}.
Filler text \autocites[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric,companion,cicero}.
Filler text \autocites[11]{companion}[10--15]{aristotle:poetics}{aristotle:rhetoric,gaonkar,vangennep}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that applying the format to `labelname` makes `\citeauthor` set in small capitals. To avoid this under styles with citation tracking enabled, `\ifmknamesc` can be refined:

```
\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ ( test {\ifbibliography} or test {\ifbool{citetracker}} )
               and ( test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
                     or test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
                     or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}}
                          and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) ) }}
```

Under styles without tracking, `\citeauthor` can be modified directly:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \let\ifmknamesc=\ifbibliography%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

To avoid use of small capitals in citations entirely, we can use the test `\ifbibliography`. The following definition also limits `\textsc` to the first author (or editor).

```
\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}
               and test {\ifbibliography}
               and ( test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
                     or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}}
                          and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) ) }}
```

One style-specific consideration is the `idem` abbreviation. In the example it is not set in small capitals. To change this you can redefine the `cite:idem` bibliography macro.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:idem}{%
  \textsc{\bibstring[\mkibid]{idem\thefield{gender}}}%
  \setunit{\nametitledelim}}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I get this error `! Undefined control sequence.
\iffirstname ->\ifboolexpr 
                           { test {\ifnumequal {\value {listcount}}{1}} and ...` What am I doing wrong? I've tried it with my tex file and with the code you've posted in your answer.

Comment: @Mario For your attempt with the example I posted - did you use an exact copy of the code? It's generally hard to troubleshoot without more information (MWE, biblatex version, etc).

Comment: biblatex version is **biblatex.sty,v 0.8i** and latex is **LaTeX2e** I didn't forget to include `\def\iffirstname` cause I 've made a copy/paste of your code.

Comment: @Mario You're definitely in need of an update - the current version is 1.6. If this doesn't fix the problem, feel free to comment/post back here.

Comment: Thank you. I think I need to update texlive, not only biblatex.sty. ;)

Comment: Now I have Texlive 2011 and it works! Thank you. One more question: how can I get **GOOSSENS, Michel, Frank MITTELBACH** instead of **GOOSSENS, Michel, Frank Mittelbach**?

Comment: @Mario Good to hear. I've added some code to the post that should give you this format.

Comment: I'm using the citetracker and the problem is that biblatex doesn't keep small caps when op. cit. For example: **J. Derrida, op. cit., p. 190** instead of **J. DERRIDA, op. cit., p. 190**. How can I fix that?

Comment: @Mario In the verbose styles names in recurrent citations are taken from the `labelname` field, not directly from `author` or `editor`. Based on your example I assumed you were using the `authoryear` style. I'll edit the answer shortly.

Comment: I'm using verbose-trad1 style. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to edit the answer to use `\mkbibnamefamily` now that this is required.

Comment: @jcr, you are my live-safer. I tried to find out what I did wrong for days now, because I knew that the above answer worked in the past. Unfortunately the command `\mkbibnamefamily` can't be found in the manual (v3.4) so far ... I hope that this will be fixed in v3.5.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, it is in section 3.9.1 of the manual (p. 104 in my A4 PDF), under `\mkbibname‘namepart’`. The command is listed just below that, but misspelled `\makebibnamefamily` (as of v3.4)—this error seems to have already been corrected for the next release.