# biblatex, authoryear-icomp: brackets around the year in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, punctuation

I use `biblatex` with the cite-style `authoryear` for footnotes, which results in

> Chang et al. 2005, p. 1116.

Faculty guidelines require

> Chang et al. (2005), p. 1116.

though.

Which files need to be modified to achieve this? I could only find questions about the inline-citations or the bibliography so far.

My `biblatex` options are:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear, autocite=footnote, dashed=false, firstinits=true,
    citestyle=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\let\cite\autocite
```

I then cite via `~\cite[1116]{chang05x}`.

Comment: Meh, found it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30822/10434

Comment: Does this answer help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30819/problem-footcite-biblatex

Comment: Note that this does not work with authoryear-icomp when multiple works of the same author occur in one citation, since the output would look like, e.g., “Knuth (1986a),b”.

Comment: True. I worked around it by simply using authoryear now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a `\foottextcite` macro based on `\textcite` (i.e., with braces).

EDIT: The example now uses `style=authoryear-icomp`.

EDIT 2: Added code for new option `autocite=foottext` which maps `\autocite` to `\foottextcite`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}

% The following is based on \textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\foottextcite}[\mkbibfootnote]% [\mkbibfootnote] added
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\foottextcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\foottextcite}{\multicitedelim}
\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{foottext}[l]{\foottextcite}{\foottextcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=foottext}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=120pt% only for the example

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01,B02}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT 3: For the sake of completeness, here's the `\foottextcite` definition suitable for `authoryear`:

```
% The following is based on \textcite
\DeclareCiteCommand{\foottextcite}[\mkbibfootnote]% [\mkbibfootnote] added
  {\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {\ifbool{cbx:parens}
     {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
     {}%
   \multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}
```

Comment: This does not work with authoryear-icomp (the citestyle that @Daniel used). It gives, e.g., “Knuth (1986a); b.”

Comment: @domwass: I was only looking at the question title which said `citestyle=authoryear`.

Comment: Thank you for this great reply, lockstep. I'll work through this now. It might be superior to the other option, because I could still use the icomp-version of authoryear.

Comment: When trying this approach using authoryear-icomp, `\autocite[88]{A01}` leads to "Author, A. (2001, p. 88).". Using [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30819/problem-footcite-biblatex/30850#30850) by @lockstep formats it as desired: "Author, A. (2001), p.88." However, `\textcite[88]{A01}` will now put brackets around the year, too. "Author ([2001], p.88)".
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Issue posted as a [separate question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298778/biblatex-authoryear-icomp-parenthesis-in-footnotes-and-textcite).

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\textcite` for in text citations complete with parentheses. If this is your preferred citation, then you can make this the default behaviour of the `\cite` command like so:

```
\let\cite\textcite
```

Comment: This answer is actually inapplicable. It's not clear from the question, but I think the OP is looking for footnote citations with parentheses. Still, for anyone else, this might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I indeed require footnote-citation. The problem seems solved though.