# Citation: Biblatex / biber square brackets

Tags: biblatex, citing, brackets

I have an issue I was not able to solve by now.
When I use the `\textcite` command in combination with a page number, the year is enclosed in square brackets.
How can I delete them?

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    bibliography=totoc,
    toc=listof,
    chapterentrydots=on,
    captions=tableheading,
    headings=small,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[
    format=hang,
    skip=2.5pt,
    justification=RaggedRight,
    singlelinecheck=false,
    labelfont=bf,
]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citetracker=true,
    autolang=other,
    style=authoryear,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist=true,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false
]{biblatex}
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% --- Backslash Authors --- % \newcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{}
\newcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\slash}
\newcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\slash}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \let\revsdnamedelim\citerevsdnamedelim
    \let\multinamedelim\citemultinamedelim%
    \let\finalnamedelim\citefinalnamedelim%
}

% --- Semikolon --- %
\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}


% --- () footnotes % --- () year footnotes
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

% --- () year text \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{% \iffieldundef{labelyear} {}% {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
\printfield[]{labelyear}% \printfield[]{extrayear}% }% }% }

% --- authors footnotes / small caps text --- %
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\AtBeginBibliography{%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textrm{#1}}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\bibliography{Master}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{Master.bib}

@article{Beasley.2008,
    author = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and  Warr, Richard},
    year = {2008},
    title = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior
             executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
    pages = {311--332},
    pagination = {page},
    volume = {23},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
    abstract = {},
    note = {}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\noindent Here I use the \textit{cite} command:
\cite[][311]{Beasley.2008} \\ Here the \textit{footcite} command: See
footnote\footcite[][311]{Beasley.2008} \\ And finally the
\textit{textcite} command:
\textcolor{red}{\textcite[][311]{Beasley.2008}}  \\ \noindent But it
should look like that: \textcolor{green}{\textsc{Beasley} et al.
(2008, p. 311)}

\end{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the `\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}...` definition.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike, but then my footcites change. The year is not enclosed in brackets anymore. Before: Beasley et al. (2008), p. 311. After Beasley et al. 2008, p. 311.

Comment: Then change the bibhyperrefparens format (needs a current biblatex): `\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\ifcsstring{blx@delimcontext}{textcite}
 {\bibhyperref{#1}}
 {\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}}
`

Comment: % --- () footnotes
% --- () year footnotes
%\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}} 
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\ifcsstring{blx@delim‌​context}{textcite}{\bibhyperref{#1}}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}} 
   
% --- () year text
\renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
\iffieldundef{labelyear}
{}%
{\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
\printfield[]{labelyear}%
\printfield[]{extrayear}%
}%
}%
}

Comment: I have modified my TEX file as you can see above. Unfortunately I get an ERROR: "! Missing \endcsname inserted." When  (Sorry for the format - how can I insert a code properly?)) :(

Comment: Perhaps your biblatex is outdated. Don't insert code in the comments, you can edit your question.

Comment: What output exactly do you expect from the different cite commands? Do you want a `\textcite`-like output from `\cite` and `\footcite` as well? Would you expect there to be a difference between `\cite` and `\textcite`?

Comment: Note that in your MWE a few line breaks seem to have one awry, so that a few lines are commented even though they shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both the `cite` and `textcite` bibmacros use `cite:labelyear+extrayear` you should not insert the parentheses there.

An easy solution is to define a new macro with parentheses and use that in `cite`

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    citetracker=true,
    autolang=other,
    style=authoryear,
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=99,
    uniquename=false,
    uniquelist=true,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AtEveryCitekey{\ifciteseen{}{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}}}

\renewcommand*{\revsdnamedelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\slash}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

\renewcommand*{\multilistdelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\finallistdelim}{\multilistdelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperrefparens}{\bibhyperref{\mkbibparens{#1}}}

\newbibmacro*{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}{%
  \iffieldundef{labelyear}
    {}
    {\printtext[bibhyperrefparens]{%
       \printfield{labelyear}%
       \printfield{extrayear}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \usebibmacro{cite:parens:labelyear+extrayear}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@article{Beasley.2008,
    author = {Beasley, Mark and Pagach, Don and  Warr, Richard},
    year = {2008},
    title = {Information conveyed in hiring announcements of senior
             executives overseeing enterprise-wide risk management processes},
    pages = {311--332},
    pagination = {page},
    volume = {23},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Accounting, Auditing {\&} Finance},
    abstract = {},
    note = {}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent Here I use the \textit{cite} command:
\cite[][311]{Beasley.2008} \\ Here the \textit{footcite} command: See
footnote\footcite[][311]{Beasley.2008} \\ And finally the
\textit{textcite} command:
\textcolor{red}{\textcite[][311]{Beasley.2008}}  \\ \noindent But it
should look like that: \textcolor{green}{\textsc{Beasley} et al.
(2008, p. 311)}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

please note how I simplified your code, especially the `\citemultinamedelim` bit.

[image: example output]

Comment: You might also be interested in [biblatex, authoryear-icomp: brackets around the year in footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39919/35864).

Comment: Thank you very much - it works perfectly! Thank you too, @Ulrike !