# biblatex - year in parentheses for references with authoryear?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing, punctuation

According to guidelines, besides printing the year in parentheses in the bibliography (which is working by default), I must have the year in parentheses for the references. Also, I have to use references in footnotes.

[Here is the mwe.](http://pastebin.com/CEaQfrfV)

Comment: Oh, it is, thanks! Don't know how to mark your comment as the solution though. Also, the macro provided [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30819/problem-footcite-biblatex) produces a space between the opening parenthesis and the year, so I added `%` behind every opening bracket.

Comment: We'll close this question as a duplicate, but you can upvote my answer to the original question.