# How to get to a specific citation and bibliography style?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am currently preparing a LaTeX-project for a paper I was asked to write and the requirements concerning citation and bibliography style are somewhat peculiar from my point of view. At least there isn't really any style quite close to it that I could find.

The following should describe the desired style pretty much:

## Citations

All citations should be made in footnotes.

### Indirect

Cf. *Chong* (2000), p. 9.

Cf. *Chong/Eggleton* (2003), pp. 166f.

Cf. *Chong et al.* (2003), pp. 166-168.

### Direct

as above, only without the Cf. part

## Bibliography

**Chong, V. K./Eggleton, I. R. C. (2003):** The decision-facilitating role of man-agement accounting systems on managerial performance: The influence of locus of control and task uncertainty, in: Advances in Accounting, vol. 20, no. 1, 2003, pp. 165–197.

**Merchant, K. A./van der Stede, W. A. (2012):** Management control systems. Performance measurement, evaluation and incentives, 3. edition, Harlow 2012.

**Hilz-Ward, R. M./Everling, O. (eds.) (2009):** Risk Performance Management. Chancen für ein besseres Rating, 1. edition, Wiesbaden 2009.

**Lomitschka, M. (2009):** Integriertes Risiko-/Chancenmanagement als Instrument der Unternehmenssteuerung, in: Hilz-Ward, R. M./Everling, O. (eds.), Risk Performance Management. Chancen für ein besseres Rating, 1. edition, Wiesbaden 2009, pp. 277–291.

**Standard & Poor's (2001):** Corporate Ratings Criteria, URL: regulationbodyofknowledge.org/wp-content/2013/03/StandardAndPoors_Corporate_Ratings_Criteria.pdf (April 29, 2014).

Furthermore it would be nice to have kind of a reference-form in-text for the articles/books, pretty much as in the citation but just author(s)-year, as in Chong/Eggleton (2003).

So my question now is, how to get there in the easiest way. I made a .bst-file via makebst which already gives me:

[1] **Archer, S./ Delvaille, P./ McLeay, S.**: A statistical model of international accounting harmonization, in: Abacus, vol. 32, no. 1, (1996), pp. 1–29.

which is reasonably close, but it's still quite a long way and I only came to realize afterwards that I would have to make any changes directly in the .bst-file. Most importly, I do not want any numbering in the bibliography and just an alphabetical ordering according to author names.

Is it possible to achieve the abovementionned style in LaTeX? Which would be the recommended way to go? It should be said at this point that I'm still open to using biblatex/biber etc. if that made more sense.

I would be thankful for any kind of advice.

Comment: Please have a look at the posting [Is there an (easy) way to create or personalize .bst files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/96174/5001)

Comment: There are quite a lot of `.bst` styles out there and you can find many collections of styles on the web, on this site we have [Where can I find collections of bibliography styles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35040/35864). Then you can use `makebst` which allows quite some customisation, but there are limits to what the wizard can do for you, so some manual work might be needed. Finally you can switch to `biblatex` ([What to do to switch to biblatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864)) whose styles don't use reverse Polish notation but something more LaTeX-y.

Comment: This looks like something one might be able to achieve with `biblatex` staring from `authoryear` with some modifications. General modifications are explained in [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864). Some of the modifications you need will certainly have been addressed here, cf. [biblatex, authoryear-icomp: brackets around the year in footnotes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39919/35864), [Problem Footcite Biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30819/35864)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm not quite sure if it is desired here to answer one's own questions, but since I obtained a solution that gets me pretty much where I wanted to get, I wanted to provide that full-scale solution here. Anyway, it is some extensive code and quite certainly not the most efficient way to cope with the requirements. Here we go:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,parentracker=false,uniquename=false,
sortcites,sorting=nyt,maxnames=2,minnames=1,maxbibnames=1000,isbn=false,url=false,
doi=false,eprint=false,urldate=long]{biblatex}
    \urlstyle{same} %maybe useful, placing needs to be tested
    \addbibresource{Testbib.bib}
    \addbibresource{Rating3.bib}

    %\usepackage{breakurl}          %vmtl. nicht nötig

    %++++++++++++ Defintion Strings ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    references = {Bibliography},
    urlseen = {},
    andothers = {\em et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}
    }

    %++++++++++++ Formatierungen Bib-Style ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1},}              %Deletes ''''
    \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{{#1},}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{{#1},}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{{#1},}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{booktitle}{{#1}}

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{vol. #1}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{volume}{}

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{no. #1}
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{{#1}}

    \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}#1}}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{{URL}\addcolon\space#1}   %\url{} um #1 entfernt \mkbibacro %evtl. \newline vor URL oder #1 einfügen

    %Edition
    \DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{%
      \ifstrequal{#1}{1}
         {}
         {{#1}. edition, }}

    %%% General
    %Interligne entre les items Biblio
    \DeclareFieldFormat{shorthandwidth}{#1}
    \setlength{\bibitemsep}{6pt}

    %% Slashes zwischen Autoren/Editoren in Bib
    \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}
    \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addslash}


    %%% Citation
    %% Slashes zwischen Autoren/Editoren
    \newcommand*{\citerevsdnamedelim}{\slash}
    \newcommand*{\citemultinamedelim}{\slash}
    \newcommand*{\citefinalnamedelim}{\slash}
    \newcommand*{\citeandothersdelim}{\addspace}

    % Adapt citation in TeX
    \AtEveryCite{%
    \let\revsdnamedelim\citerevsdnamedelim
    \let\multinamedelim\citemultinamedelim
    \let\finalnamedelim\citefinalnamedelim
    \let\andothersdelim\citeandothersdelim
    \renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
    %\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\mkbibempf{#1}}  %needs to be included if it is opted to include first name initials for distinction in the footnotes
    }

    %++++++++++++ New Bib Macros ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    \newbibmacro*{url+urldate}{%
      \usebibmacro{url}%
      \iffieldundef{urlyear}
        {}
        {\setunit*{\addspace}%
         \usebibmacro{urldate}}}

    %Makro für Editornamen in inbook
    \DeclareNameFormat{edname}{%
        \usebibmacro{name:last-first-edname}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}%
        \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

    %Makro für Editornamen in inbook    
    \newbibmacro*{name:last-first-edname}[4]{%
      \ifuseprefix
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
         \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{%
           \ifcapital
             {\MakeCapital{#3}\isdot}
             {#3\isdot}%
           \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
         #1\isdot
         \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd#4\isdot}%
         \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd#2\isdot}}
        {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
         \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
         #1\isdot
         \ifblank{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimd#4\isdot}%
         \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
         \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd#2\isdot}%
         \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd#3\isdot}}}

    %editor for inbook
    \makeatletter       
    \newbibmacro*{editorinbold}{%
    \ifthenelse {\ifuseeditor\AND\NOT\ifnameundef{editor}}
    {\ifthenelse {\iffieldequals{author}{editor}\AND
    \NOT\iffirstonpage}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\printnames[edname]{editor}\addspace
    \savefield{namehash}{\bbx@lasthash}}%
    \mkbibparens{\usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
    \clearname{editor}}
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}
    \makeatother

    \renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<---- was \setunit*{\adddot}%
      \printfield{number}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \printfield{eid}%
        \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
        \printfield{year}}

    \renewbibmacro*{journal}{%
        \printfield{journaltitle}%
        \addcomma\space%
        }

   \DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{%
    \iffirstinits
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}

    %Code for bold author names and year in bibliography
    \renewbibmacro*{author}{%
      \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseauthor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
      }
        {\mkbibbold{%       
            \printnames{author}%
        \addspace{%
            \mkbibparens{%
            {\printfield{year}}}}%
            \addcolon}%
         \iffieldundef{authortype}
           {}
           {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}}
        {}}

    %Code for bold editor names and year in bibliography        
    \renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{%
      \ifboolexpr{
        test \ifuseeditor
        and
        not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
      }
        {\mkbibbold{%
            \printnames{editor}%
        \addspace{%
             \mkbibparens{%
         \usebibmacro{editorstrg}}%
             \addspace
             \mkbibparens{%
            {\printfield{year}}}%
             \addcolon}%
         \clearname{editor}}
        {}}}

    \renewbibmacro*{cite:labelyear+extrayear}{%
      \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[bibhyperref]{%
           \printfield[parens]{labelyear}%
           \printfield[parens]{extrayear}}}}  % Klammern um Jahr bei Citations
```

And then I declared some new **BibliographyDrivers**

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{editorbold}% changes from {byeditor+others}
  %\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  %\printfield{volumes}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{series+number}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\printfield{note}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%publisher+
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{year}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  %\newunit
  %\printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%+++++++++++++++ Inbook +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inbook}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \usebibmacro{bybookauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
    \usebibmacro{editorinbold}% <--- NEU
    \addcomma\space
    %\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock% <--- NEU
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
    \addcomma
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
    \setunit{\addspace}%
    \printfield{year}%      Neu eingefügt
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

%+++++++++++++++ Online +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  %\printlist{language}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  %\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \printfield{version}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:eprint}
    {\usebibmacro{eprint}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Any comments are certainly very welcome.

Comment: The only thing though that I couldn't quite wrap my head around is that in some cases citing the inbook triggers the appearance of the corresponding book in the bibliography and at other times it doesn't. Any hints to why this could be the case?

Answer (score -1):

I have had to make the same decision, and I am now very happy I went with `biblatex`. If you have to customize bibliography or citation styles, I find it much easier to learn than `bibtex`. 
I cannot remember much about the internal workings of `bibtex` anymore, due to the fact that I decided against it over two years ago. I do remember, however, that I found it hard to get good documentation covering style customization during my first attempts. This is different for `biblatex`; the documentation supplied with it is very usable and certainly more helpful than anything I could write here. Except in two rather complicated cases I never needed additional docu.

I recommend having a look at the documentation and also into a style file from both `bibtex` and `biblatex` and then decide what scares you less.

Comment: This posting reads more like a comment than a full answer. Could you maybe provide a few examples of how you've gone about customizing the appearance of the formatted bibliography?

Comment: Well, hovering over the `add a comment` widget produced a text that this should only be used for clarifications or questions.