# Style surname according to keywords field

Tags: biblatex, formatting

How do I make surnames in a bibliography small caps, *except* for 'author' when the keyword is 'primary'? Yes, I know I could just \textsc{…} them all, but I'd like this to be automated.

I suppose the answer to my question will be derivative of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29862/60686.

---

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{roehrs2014,
    author = {Dorian Roehrs},
    title = {Inflections on Pre-Nominal Adjectives in Germanic},
    subtitle = {Main types, Subtypes, and Subset Relations},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Comparative Germanic Linguistics},
    journalshorttitle = {JCGL},
    volume = {18},
    year = {2015},
    pages = {213--271},
    doi = {10.1007/s10828-015-9076-z},
    keywords = {secondary},
}

@inbook{iwein-dkv,
    author = {Hartmann von Aue},
    title = {Iwein},
    booktitle = {Gregorius -- Der arme Heinrich -- Iwein},
    editor = {Volker Mertens},
    translator = {Volker Mertens},
    publisher = {Deutscher Klassiker Verlag},
    location = {Frankfurt/Main},
    year = {2008},
    series = {Deutscher Klassiker Verlag im Taschenbuch},
    number = {29},
    pages = {317--767},
    keywords = {primary},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{roehrs2014}\autocite{roehrs2014} and \citeauthor{iwein-dkv}\autocite{iwein-dkv}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title={Primary Sources}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title={Secondary Sources}, heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

---

The way I want it, "Roehrs" and "Mertens" would be in small caps, while "von Aue" would be in normal type (ignoring that 'von Aue' is like 'da Vinci' not strictly speaking a surname, but whatever).

Comment: See also [biblatex set author font based on bib field](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/267712/35864) and [Use small caps in bibliography for institutional authors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166305/35864).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `\ifkeyword` inside `\mkbibnamelast`

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifkeyword{primary}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}
```

to check for `primary` only, but you can combine this with the more sophiscticated solution in [Set author's last name in small caps but avoid them for editors, translators, etc using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29861/35864) to

```
\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
               or test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
               or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}} and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) }}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{primary}} and test {\ifmknamesc}}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}
```

You can apply the same to `\mkbibnameprefix` for the "von" part, `\mkbibnamefirst` for first names and `\mkbibnameaffix` for the "junior" part.
In the MWE we change the last name and "von" part, but leave the rest as is.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{roehrs2014,
    author = {Dorian Roehrs},
    title = {Inflections on Pre-Nominal Adjectives in Germanic},
    subtitle = {Main types, Subtypes, and Subset Relations},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Comparative Germanic Linguistics},
    journalshorttitle = {JCGL},
    volume = {18},
    year = {2015},
    pages = {213--271},
    doi = {10.1007/s10828-015-9076-z},
    keywords = {secondary},
}

@inbook{iwein-dkv,
    author = {Hartmann von Aue},
    title = {Iwein},
    booktitle = {Gregorius -- Der arme Heinrich -- Iwein},
    editor = {Volker Mertens},
    translator = {Volker Mertens},
    publisher = {Deutscher Klassiker Verlag},
    location = {Frankfurt/Main},
    year = {2008},
    series = {Deutscher Klassiker Verlag im Taschenbuch},
    number = {29},
    pages = {317--767},
    keywords = {primary},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\def\ifmknamesc{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifcurrentname{labelname}}
               or test {\ifcurrentname{author}}
               or ( test {\ifnameundef{author}} and test {\ifcurrentname{editor}} ) }}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{primary}} and test {\ifmknamesc}}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifkeyword{primary}} and test {\ifmknamesc}}
    {#1}
    {\textsc{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\citeauthor{roehrs2014}\autocite{roehrs2014} and \citeauthor{iwein-dkv}\autocite{iwein-dkv}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=primary, title={Primary Sources}, heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[keyword=secondary, title={Secondary Sources}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: I didn't get around to updating the example image to the new MWE using the more elaborate code, so Mertens is currently not small-capsed.

Comment: That was more straightforward than I expected from browsing the Bibtex documentation last night :) Thank you.